# On The Consistency of Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

There's a certain mathematical "phenomenon" that I don't seem to grasp. Presented the equation: $x^2 + 4x + 4 = 0$, we can readily find that the equation has exactly 1 solution ($x = –2$). However, when we isolate $x^2$ and take the square root of both sides, we get the equality $x = \sqrt{–4x – 4}$. However, this equality has zero roots. I don't quite understand why, though. I previously thought that any root of the first equation must also be a root of the second. If not, then when is it the case that roots are transfered from one equation to another? Thank you in advance.

Comment: $x^2=-4x-4\iff x=\pm \sqrt{-4x-4}$

Comment: No, I mean what if I decide to take the principal positive square root only. Or better, imagine we start with the equation $\sqrt{7x + 8} = x$ for example. Then to find solutions, I would square both sides and solve the quadratic. The solutions of the quadratic would be $8, –1$. However $–1$ doesn't satisfy the initial equation.

Comment: To have a clear question you need a clear start. If the start is: Solve the equation $x=\sqrt{-4x-4}$ and if the first step is "squaring both sides", then you have to take care which is the correct implication. Then you may want to write down propositions like: "**If** $a$ is a solution of the equation $x=\sqrt{-4x-4}$, **then** $a$ is also a solution of the equation $x^2 =-4x-4$. We are going in one direction at this point. Then we solve the last equation and get $a=-2$ the unique solution. Finished? No. We still have to do something. Well, it is enough to check if this $a$ is also a sol...

Comment: Hold on, why is it a one way? I always thought is was a biconditional. As in $a$ is a solution of the first equation if and only if $a$ is a solution of the second. Is this not the case?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions#Other_operations) may help

Comment: It's biconditional if and only if the operation you perform is reversible, which is usually equivalent to applying a bijective operation to both sides of the equality.

Comment: With each algebraic operation except for addition and subtraction (without altering the balance), you change the equation "system" to another one. Try to plot $y=\sqrt{7x+8}$ and $y=x^{2}-7x-8$. They are represent 2 different graphs but they intersect at $x=-1, x=8$. Hence, each graph/equation has its set of roots and properties.

Comment: For real $x$ such that $x^2+4x+4=0$, we have $x^2+4x+4=0$$\iff x^2=-4x-4$ and $-4x-4\geqslant 0$$\iff x^2=-4x-4$ and $x\leqslant -1$$\iff x=-\sqrt{-4x-4}$ and $x\leqslant -1$.

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT: You can note that the equation $x^2+4x+4=0$ is equivalent to $(x+2)^2=0$ so $x=-2$ is the only solution (it is a double root so "two" roots because it is a quadratic equation of one unknown over a field, which is $\mathbb Q$. On the other hand
$x^2+4x+4=0$ is equivalent to $x=\pm\sqrt{-4x-4}$ and it is also an equation to be  solved. We can see that the only solution is $x=-2$ (It could not be otherwise!) and the signe "+" must be discarded because, simply, it does not satisfy the equation. (This is usual in a lot of problems).